# What are the differences between indistinguishable and identical?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, terminology, identical-particles

What is the difference between indistinguishable particles and [identical particles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_particles)?

Comment: As far as I know, these are just two different names with the same meaning.

Comment: I've been doing physics for a while now, and I've never heard these terms used for different things; I agree with @C.R.

Comment: The two terms are apparently often used indiscriminately, cf. first paragraph on this [Wikipedia page (May 2014)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_particles).

Comment: Very good question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I create an electron on earth and someone else creates an electron on Andromeda, they're identical particles.  They have the same quantum numbers, they're both excitations of the electron field.  However they're distinguishable by means of their spatial separation.  Their wavefunctions don't overlap.

Edit: perhaps I should add that not everyone uses the two words in this strict sense.  Sometimes they're used interchangeably, but blurring them carries with it the danger of taking seriously the entanglement implied by antisymmetrizing across all existing electrons.

Comment: I'm skeptical that this is standard, but I like it!

Comment: @joshphysics  for more information to allay your skepticism, see [here](http://motls.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/energy-measurements-in-two-fermion.html)

Comment: To put it another way, if they weren't distinguishable, then whenever I solve the Schrodinger equation for an electron, I'd have to solve it for all the electrons in the universe, using an antisymmetrized wavefunction.

Comment: Thanks!  I think the distinction you draw is very useful, and I'll certainly propagate this terminology to my students in the future.

Comment: @josh and twistor: Probably a less ambiguous word for this than 'distinguishable' would be 'distinct'.

Comment: @twistor59 I think one always Should anti-symmetrize the wavefunction but we choose not to since the error introduced by consideration in calculation is usually insignificant. But nothing really stop us from saying that, if we swap the two electrons wavefunction of universe picks up a minus sign simply as consequence that they are spin-half particles.
To put it explicitly electron in andromeda and electron on earth are only Effectively distinguishable.

Comment: twistor59, you seem to mix field theory of electron with wave functions of non-relativistic theory; it would be better to answer within one of the two schemes. Also, considering such fantastic situation as creating electron on Earth and in Andromeda which nobody ever witnessed seems too far from the setting where the terms "indistinguishable", "identical particle" were originally conceived and used.

Comment: This answer is vague. If I bring two particles closer and closer together so that there is more and more wavefunction overlap, at what point do I get to say that they are no longer distinguishable?

Comment: This is very interesting. Although they're identical particles, the quantum state of the two electrons will be different, even though they have the same quantum numbers. I hope this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Two particles are the same if you can't tell the difference, that is if the exchanging operator commutes with all observables. In this QM context thus indistinguishable and identical particles mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between indistinguishable particles and identical particles?

This is one of those cases where language problems make quantum theory nightmare to learn. In daily life, two things are *identical* when it is hard or impossible to tell the difference in their properties by casual examination. For example, two xerox copies of the same document, two balls from the same metal bearing etc. This does not mean that they are absolutely the same. In daily life there is no such pair, but we want to use the word identical.

*Indistinguishable* in daily life means pretty much the same thing.

In case of electrons, we call them identical because they have the same charge and mass and possibly other parameters (spin...) for similar reasons as we call two xerox copies identical.

But for electrons the word *indistinguishable* is often used in a different sense than the above daily sense. What people often mean is that in the atom, one cannot follow electrons in time to maintain the knowledge of which is which. In this sense, in classical physics identical particles are distinguishable, but in quantum theory identical particles are indistinguishable, because *we cannot look and track the electron in the atom*.

What is of greater importance, however, is that it was found that description of two  or more electrons in an atom is in best agreement with measurements when *anti-symmetric* Hamiltonian eigenfunction is used. This is such that no difference between the properties of any two different electrons can be derived from it. That is also one meaning of "electrons are indistinguishable". If they were described by function that is neither symmetric nor anti-symmetric, predictions for one electron would be different than for the other and the electrons would be distinguishable in this sense. But in atom only anti-symmetric functions seem to be appropriate.

For large enough systems or separations, all this loses validity. For example, the electron in your fingernail is of course distinguishable from the electron in my tooth. Anti-symmetric wave functions are inappropriate for such cases.

Sometimes, by indistinguishable people mean "the two electrons do not have individuality", "interchange of two electrons is not a real event" or even "all the electrons are just one electron" or similar weird stuff, but there is little evidence for that in physics.